# Typing custom event with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm asking for a suggest on how to type correctly the schema for how an EventObject should be, including what's inside the "extendedProps" key.

As of now I've done it like this:

```
interface ICustomExtendedProps {
  privateNote?: string;
  publicNote?: string;
  owner: { id: number; name: string };
  guest: { id: number; name: string };
  status: EventStatus;
}

export interface CustomEventInput extends EventInput {
  extendedProps?: ICustomExtendedProps;
}
```

Then I created some mock data using this schema and passed them directly inside the **event** key in the fullcalendar component.

The thing is that I'm creating various kind of custom views using selfmade eventContent components. But now inside the eventContent callback I get the event as a **EventApi** object, which loses all the custom types I declared before.

Probably this is really a beginner question, but how am I supposed to have consistency in the types?

edit: I'm adding the **eventContent** cb snippet

```
<FullCalendar
    views={{
      dayGridMonth: {
        eventContent: ({ event }) => (
          <DayGridMonthCustomView
            eventData={event}
            onClickHandler={eventClickHandler.bind(null, event)}
          />
        )
      },
    }} 
/>
```

The **event** argument I get from the callback is of the type **EventApi**, I'm not losing the data inside the event, I'm losing only the type since fullcalendar doesn't know the shape of the event.

Comment: Is it losing only the custom types, itself, or just the custom data?  Can you add the `eventContent` callback to your example?

Comment: Hi @TonyN, I updated the example, as I specified I'm not losing the data, it's just that I have to access it without type safety!

Comment: Does `eventContent: ({ event }) => (` -> `eventContent: ({ event } : { event: CustomEventInput }) => (` or `eventData={event}` -> `eventData={event as unknown as CustomEventInput}` work? (Not intended as an answer - just to flesh out the question more)

Comment: I'm trying to cast it as you said in the second example, and it seems to be working!

Comment: I took a try at writing an answer, but I think you should also wait to see if anyone else provides something.

Answer (score 0):

**Double assertion**

I use this often in the case of event callbacks, particularly when third party libraries are involved.

For some more details see "TypeScript Deep Dive"'s [section on double assertions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion) ([github mirror](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/120b111/docs/types/type-assertion.md))

```
<FullCalendar
    views={{
      dayGridMonth: {
        eventContent: ({ event }) => (
          <DayGridMonthCustomView
            eventData={(event as unknown) as CustomEventInput}
            onClickHandler={eventClickHandler.bind(null, event)}
          />
        )
      },
    }} 
/>
```

**Is there a better option?**

I don't consider this particularly ideal for some reason. Maybe the nature of events and third party libraries will leave the user no choice.

There are two cases I can think of recently that in the official docs that may interest those reading into [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown):

- [Mixins: Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#decorators-and-mixins-4881) has an example where extra interface data is added to an object:

  ```js
  // The runtime aspect could be manually replicated via
  // type composition or interface merging.
  type FreezablePlayer = Player & { shouldFreeze: boolean };

  const playerTwo = (new Player() as unknown) as FreezablePlayer;
  playerTwo.shouldFreeze;
  ```
- [TypeScript 4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html)'s release notes: [Control Flow Analysis of Aliased Conditions and Discriminants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) and [Using `unknown` in Catch Variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#using-unknown-in-catch-variables).